# Crash accessing static variable UIFont

Tags: ios, swift, static, crash, uifont

Swift application. I have a Theme class declared including the following:

```swift
class Theme {    
    enum Font {
        static let header1         = UIFont(name: "IBM Plex Sans Bold", size: 32)! 
        static let header2         = UIFont(name: "IBM Plex Sans Bold", size: 20)! // Crash
        static let pickerTitleFont = UIFont(name: "IBM Plex Sans Bold", size: 17)!
        static let navBarFont      = UIFont(name: "IBM Plex Sans Bold", size: 28)!  // Crash
    }
}
```

In appDelegate, I have a routine that sets up a navigation bar appearance proxy,

```swift
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
                                          NSAttributedString.Key.font: Theme.Font.navBarFont]
```

Sometimes (very rarely), when running this app, a crash occurs.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000104d5a7c0
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process: exc handler [19751]

Triggered by Thread:  0


Kernel Triage:
VM - pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage


Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   ---                             0x0000000104d5a7c0 one-time initialization function for pickerTitleFont + 140
1   ---                             0x0000000104d5a7a4 one-time initialization function for pickerTitleFont + 112
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b8550f88 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b85527d4 _dispatch_once_callout + 32 (once.c:52)
4   ---                             0x0000000104d77104 Theme.Font.navBarFont.unsafeMutableAddressor + 20 (Theme.swift:75)
5   ---                             0x0000000104d77104 AppDelegate.setupNavigationController(root:) + 1188 (AppDelegate.swift:152)
```

How can this crash be occurring? It's simply accessing a statically defined variable.
The crash does not clearly state why the crash occurred.

Its very odd that the crash appears to be caused by accessing `Font.navBarFont` however lower in the stack trace it says its `pickerTitleFont`.

This crash has also occurred when accessing `header2` font setting the font on a label in a view.

Comment: I think because of some reason system is unable to load the custom font. So that the ```UIFont``` returns nil

Comment: Generally agree, but why? This is a very rare occurrence. The font is present and normally loads fine.

Comment: since it is very rare it may be a resource shortage or a memory constraint. not sure.